# sending Email with current path of asp file

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I want to create a asp file that once its opened it will send an Email to me with its Current location in Server, I am really new to ASP and I searched the internet on how to do so but I failed, also there is no Mail server on the server, any Ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean Classic ASP or ASP.net - they're very different and you.ve used both tags.  Here's a Classic ASP tutorial http://chrishardy.co.uk/asp/tutorials/email-cdosys.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just replace example data with yours.
I assume that by "Current location in Server" your mean reqest path.

```
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.Subject = "Subject";
        mail.Body = string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", Request.Path);
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@exampledomain.com");
        mail.To.Add("recipient@exampledomain.com");

        var smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "mail.exampledomain.com";
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@exampledomain.com", "{sender_password_here}");
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
}
```